# Ruby - undefined method `/' for "90 kilograms":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I tried to make a simple program that asks the user a few questions.

I wanted the program to assume the user was from America, but to convert the measures if the user gave answers in the metric system. Here is the code:

```
    print "How old are you?"
    age = gets.chomp()

    print "Ok, how tall are you?"
    height = gets.chomp()
    if height.include? "centimeters"
        height = height * 2.54
    else
        height = height

    print "How much do you weigh?"
    weight = gets.chomp()
    if weight.include? "kilograms"
        weight = weight / 2.2
    else
        weight = weight 

    puts "So, you're #{age} years old, #{height} tall and #{weight} pounds heavy."
```

I ran the code and it was fine. I was able to enter in all my data until I got to the last bit about the weight. I tested it by entering in 90 kilograms, but got the following error message:

```
ex11.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `/' for "90 kilograms":String (NoMethodError)
```

It looks like it's not accepting my division operator. Does anyone know what's up here?

Comment: You have to coerce your string to an integer by using `.to_i`, first.

Comment: It shouldn't be fine. Your code is not valid Ruby code.

Comment: Also, there are some redundancies in your code. `height = height * 2.54` can be simplified into `height = height * 2`, or `height *= 2`, and `height = height` and `weight = weight` are doing nothing.

Answer (score 4):

There are conceptually many things wrong with your approach:
First Thing:  `"1 centmeter" * 2` is  `"1 centmeter1 centmeter"`  so although that is syntactically correct , but i am pretty sure thats not what you want.

Try this(this rejects everything from the input except integers):

```
print "How old are you?"
age = gets.chomp()

print "Ok, how tall are you?"
height = gets.chomp()
if height.include? "centimeters"
    height = height.gsub(/[^0-9]/,"").to_i * 2.54
else
    height = height

print "How much do you weigh?"
weight = gets.chomp()
if weight.include? "kilograms"
    weight = weight.gsub(/[^0-9]/,"").to_i / 2.2
else
    weight = weight
```

----- EDIT ----
`"1 centimer".to_i` and `"1 centimeter".gsub(\[^1-9]\,"")` both turns out to be 1. Ruby is pretty smart so i guess you can ignore the gsub part.

Comment: +1. The only thing I would change about your answer is to keep the variables of the same type. You could have height/weight as an integer or string at any point in time.

Comment: Sahil, thanks for the detailed response. After someone told me to convert the types, I quickly noticed that it was easier said than done.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the "weight" from string to an integer or a double.

Comment: I was thinking I might be doing something wrong with the users output with regards to strings :D

Thanks a bunch!